# Docked Settings Button override for Android

Tags: android, button

I am developing on a Galaxy Nexus, and I would like the settings icon on the main dock to open up some window of buttons.  How do I go about handling this button press?  it's that button that looks like a vertical "..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That button:

- will only appear on devices without a MENU button
- will only appear if you have action bar items in the overflow menu
- cannot be directly used for other purposes

You are welcome to have an action item in the action bar that will "open up some window of buttons". You can choose whatever icon you want for this action item. I strongly encourage you to **not** use the same icon as the action overflow menu. There are millions of possible icons, so surely you can choose one of greater relevance to whatever the "window of buttons" is and will not conflict with the users' expectations of what the action bar overflow should look and work like.